Short story about astronauts exploring the interior of a giant organism in space
Trying to find any info about a short story I read in a sci-fi monthly digest in the early '90s.
The basic gist is a team of astronauts is exploring and researching the interior of a large asteroid/planetoid sized object, which for all appearances, seems to be alive. There's lots of fun descriptions of the slime and fluids that are excreted from the walls of the "tunnels" which make a mess of their space suits but are an unavoidable part of their day to day exploration. I vaguely remember it being told from the point of view of a female scientist.
The story's crisis comes about as the object seems to be having seismic shifts and breaking apart as the crew is holding on for dear life. It's ultimately revealed that it's sort of like a giant flower that unfolds and blooms to reproduce, or absorb energy from the star it's orbiting, or... something.
I don't remember much else -- I was probably no older than 12 or 13 when I read it, but it's been stuck in my brain for all these years and I would love to track it down.
